# Running multiple python files in parallel

Tags: python

The following is my code. It's quite simple and straight forward, and the mission is to run three files at the same time.

When I ran it, it only runs the last processes (each file should generate a csv file).

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess

def worker(file):
    subprocess.call(["python", file])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = ["launch_day_t1.py","launch_day_t2.py","launch_day_t3.py"]
    for i in files:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker(i))
        p.start()
```

As you can see I have three files ("launch_day_t1.py","launch_day_t2.py" and "launch_day_t3.py") that I wish to run.

My question is that whether is this the best way to run parallel scripts (if it is), or is there a better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Since all you seem to do is invoke the scripts, nothing else (e.g., use the results), can't you use a command line script and fire off the three scripts while putting them in the background (this may depend somewhat on your OS). In bash for example: `for script in launch_data_t?.py; do python $script &; done`.

Comment: @Evert trying it now. So, what is an ideal scenario where I can use subprocess commands?

Comment: You're asking when to use subprocess? I'd say, for running existing programs in a much longer Python script; in particular if that script sets up the arguments to the program, and uses the results. Those programs should be ones not implemented in Python already (lots of shell commands/builtins are; look at the os module for example), and don't have a simple interface with Python.

Answer (score 0):

The best situation here would be to refactor the code in "launch_day_t1.py" so that the parts you need to call are wrapped into functions, and the cli code is `if __name_=="__main__"`'d... something that looks like:

```
#launch_day_t1.py
def do_stuff():
    pass
def do_more_stuff():
    pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_stuff()
    do_more_stuff()
```

Then instead of calling the file from the command line, you can import the parts that you need, and call it from your existing python interpreter, and that will make things like gathering up the output and such much easier.

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import launch_day_t1
import launch_day_t2

def worker(namespace):
    namespace.do_stuff()
    return namespace.do_more_stuff()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    N_CORES = 8
    files = [launch_day_t1, launch_day_t2]
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(2*N_CORES)
    print(p.map(worker, files))
```